# don't show number in alert box

Tags: javascript, php, alert

im writing a php simple code that read from a file and search for an student degree from that file. for example in my file i have:

```
123    20
456    18
789    19
```

and i want to show for example '123' degree in an alert box whith this code:

```
<?php
function show_degree($str) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $str . '")</script>';
}

$given_number="123";

$myfile = fopen("degree/dm.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($myfile)) !== false) {
    list($number, $degree) = explode("\t", $line);  
    if($number==$given_number) {
        echo $degree;
        show_degree(   'Hello:\\n\\nYour Degree:\\n'.$degree  );    
    }   
} 
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

what should i do?
tnx a lot

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does the `echo $degree` work?

Comment: @putvande, no i don't get any errors but nothing shown! yes echo $degree show my degree correctly

Comment: @putvande, are you sure this code works fine??
i tried mor than one time but didn't work :(

Comment: Your given number is 123, and you want to show 123? Don't you want to show 20 instead?

Comment: @lolka_bolka, i want to show 20 in alert box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved own question with this code:

```
<?php
function show_degree($str,$deg) {
    $deg=""+$deg;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $str .$deg. '")</script>';
}

$given_number="90222179";

$myfile = fopen("degree/dm.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($myfile)) !== false) {
    list($number, $degree) = explode("\t", $line);
    if($number==$given_number) {
        echo $degree;
        show_degree(   "Hello\\n\\nYour Degree:\\n",$degree  ); 
        }   
    } 
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: try the above answer if your line has more than one space in between.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:your `explode("\t", $line);`  is not giving the required result to you.

```
 <?php 


function show_degree($str) 
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $str . '")</script>';
}

$given_number="123";

$myfile = fopen("degree/dm.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($myfile)) !== false) 
{
    //echo $line;
    list($number, $degree) = explode(" ",preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $line));// change here

if($number==$given_number)  
{
   // echo $degree;
        show_degree(   'Hello:\\n\\nYour Degree:\\n'.$degree  );    
    }   
} 
fclose($myfile);
?>
```